# How do I embed a chatbox code into all pages of a wordpress site?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, embed

I am trying to put a chatbox on my site and I used chatango to generate the code for a chatbox. Now, I want to put the code in so that the entire site uses it, without pasting the code many times(Don't know how to do either of). I need help doing it.

Comment: create a wordpress plugin for it. My guess is there are already numerous wordpress chat plugins already available though

Answer (score 1):

Add it to the template file which your pages are using, these will be somewhere like:

wp-content/themes/{THEME_NAME}/includes/...{TEMPLATE_NAME.php}

If you are doing this with a theme you have purchased it is worth looking into creating a child theme so your changes are not overwritten when the theme is updated.

Comment: I'm using Parament theme, but the themes directory contains only confit, twenty fourteen, twenty fifteen, twenty thirteen, and an index.php file that contains only a php start tag and "silence is golden" commented out.

Comment: Okay. I was able to get the rest of the index.php file to show. Now where should I put the code? Chatango gave me a javascript code that has the script tags already on it.

Comment: Put the scripts just before the closing body tag

Comment: There are no body tags. php tag followed by get_header()?> followed by a coupe divs, then ifs, elses, whiles, and get functions in php tags

Comment: But the comments say that it is the "Main templete file" And it is the "Most generic templete file in a Wordpress theme"

Comment: Nevermind. I used the editor that's directly on the dashboard and inserted it there. Thank You very much for your help!